# SD card stuck writing single block of data

Tags: spi, sd, filesystem

I noticed a very strange behaviour on some of my micro SD cards.

I have a project that writes data to files stored on my SD card (FAT32 formatted) via the SPI interface of a PIC32 microcontroller.

General behaviour (after the SD card and filesystem has been initialized correctly) :

1. The uC sends the 'Write single block' command (0x58) together with a 4 byte address and and checksum.
2. The SD card answers a r1 respons
3. The uC sends the start token (0xFE), 512 bytes of data and 2 bytes of CRC (0xFF as no crc active)
4. The SD card answers 0x05 to confirm data is accepted
5. The SD card start its writing cycle writing the received data to its memory
6. The SD card will keep responding busy tokens (0x00) until it has finished writing the data
7. The uC keeps reading this busy tokens (0x00) untill a non 0x00 is received, telling the SD card has finished
8. The uC continues with other tasks regarding the SD card (checking attached, reading CID, sending new data,...)

What i observe now :

1. **After the SD card answered 0x05 to confirm data is accepted, it keeps sending this busy tokens (0x00) and will never again send a non 0x00 byte**
2. So it **seems the SD card is never ready with storing the data** it has been and accepted before
   In the SD driver there is a timeout of 250 ms for such cases
   -> After the timeout has occured, the SD driver will read the CID register, but will receive all 0x00 as data
   -> So the SD driver, that compares the latest received CID data with the CID on attachement, will mark the SD card as detached as the CID data doesn't match.

I have already :

1. Tried to make the timeout of 250 ms longer, even infinite by keep reading until a non-busy-token is read, but the SD card keeps returning busy tokens 0x00.
   -> It never gets out of this state. -> Even a reset command (CMD0) doens't resolve the problem. I geuss the SD card doesn't accept new commands as long as it hasn't finished its write cycle.
   -> **The only way to recover is by power-cycling the SD card**. Of course this power cycle is unwanted as I don't have a way to this this automatically.
2. Checked supply voltage stays within limits
   -> This is fine, doesn't drop a bit
3. Checked when the behaviour occurs
   -> This doens't show a pattern, neither in time, nor in the block address the data is written to
4. Observed that some SD cards show this behaviour more often than others.

Can someone help:

1. Understanding why an SD card could get into this never ending writing cycle
   -> And as such prevent this from happening
2. Figuring out a way how to get the SD card out of this state other then a power cycle whenever it does happen